# Smallest dimension for having two non similar matrices with same minimal and characteristic polynomials

Tags: matrices, polynomials

I give [here](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/two-non-similar-matrices-having-same-minimal-and-characteristic-polynomials/) the example of two non similar matrices, namely $$M=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \text{ and }
N=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$ having the same minimal and characteristic polynomials. This example is in a vector space of dimension equal to $4$.

Is it possible to find an example in dimension $3$? If yes, what are examples over fields of finite characteristic? Over fields of infinite characteristic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. This is easy to show using [Jordan canonical forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). The multiplicity of $x-\lambda$ in the characteristic polynomial is the number of appearances of $\lambda$ on the diagonal of the Jordan canonical form, while the multiplicity of $x-\lambda$ in the minimal polynomial is the size of the largest Jordan block corresponding to $\lambda$. Then one checks by hand that in dimension $3$ or less, these two quantities completely determine the Jordan canonical form. (In dimension $4$ and higher it doesn't, as your example demonstrates.)